# Why am I getting error TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to use the Maclaurin series to estimate the sine of a number. This is my function:

```
from math import sin, factorial

import numpy as np

fac = np.vectorize(factorial)

def sin_x(x, terms=10):
    """ Calcul une approximation de sin(x) en utlisant
    un nombre donné de termes de la serie de Maclaurin"""
    
    n = np.arange(terms)
    return np.sum[((-1)**n)(x**(2*n+1)) / fac(2*n+1)]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Valeur actuelle:", sin(5)) # En utilisant la fonction sinus de la librairie math
    
    print("N (terms)\tMaclaurin\tErreur")
    
    for n in range(1, 6):
        maclaurin = sin_x(5, terms=n)
        print(f"{n}\t\t{maclaurin:.03f}\t\t{sin(10) - maclaurin:.03f}")
```

and this is the error I get

```
PS C:\Users\tapef\Desktop\NUMPY-TUT> python maclaurin_sin.py
Valeur actuelle: -0.9589242746631385
N (terms)       Maclaurin       Erreur
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tapef\Desktop\NUMPY-TUT\maclaurin_sin.py", line 20, in <module>
    maclaurin = sin_x(5, terms=n)
  File "C:\Users\tapef\Desktop\NUMPY-TUT\maclaurin_sin.py", line 12, in sin_x
    return np.sum[((-1)**n)(x**(2*n+1)) / fac(2*n+1)]
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

How do I get rid of this error? Thanks

I've tried to use brackets instead of parenthetis.

Comment: What is `((-1) ** n)(x ** (2 * n + 1))`? Here is programming, not mathematical formula, do you mean `((-1) ** n) * (x ** (2 * n + 1))`? The next error you will encounter is `TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable`, because you use square brackets `[]` to call `np.sum`.

Comment: Which formula are you trying to implement at `np.sum[((-1)**(n))(x**(2*n+1)) / fac(2*n+1)]`? The `((-1)**n)` translates into an array with arguments passed as `(x**(2*n+1))` which is interpreted as function call.

Comment: A debugging hint - when you get an error in a complicated expression like that, try breaking it up into pieces.  That should make it easier to identify which step is giving you problems.  Is the the `fac(2*n+1)`?  The (x**(2*n+1))`?  etc.

Comment: Thank you all. The problem was the multiply sign as you stated and it has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the multiplication between `(-1)**n)` and `(x**(2*n+1)`. Furthermore, `np.sum()` needs to be called as a function, so your return statement becomes:

```
return np.sum(((-1)**n)*(x**(2*n+1)) / fac(2*n+1))
```